# Get lines from a specific date afterwards/backwards

Tags: shell, date, awk

I'm working on a shell script.I need to get lines which contain informations from that day or older than that. In the file each line is a record and the first line is the older the last is the latest.
The file contains:

> some info \t the date \t other info

If I simply grep the given date I find what I'm looking for but just if that date's present in the file. I find the last occurance and get the lines from the start of the file. I tried awk but I totally failed. It should give me each line what contain that date or is older. My failure and last attempt:

> awk '$1 <= "2015/03/17"'

So I need something similar to egrep but which gives me all lines with the date of 2015/03/15 or older. Or do I have to go trought each line and compare the 2 dates, according to that write out if it's older?

Comment: In you described input the _date_ is the `second` field (in tab delimited file). Could you please explain your "attempt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be pretty easy since the date format you are using can be compared as characters..

File: test.txt

```
a       2015/03/17      b
c       2015/03/12      d
e       2014/02/10      f
g       2016/01/01      h
```

Awk command:

```
awk -v d="2015/03/15" '{if ($2 <= d) {print $0}}' test.txt
```

Just change d= to whatever date value you want.